# cannot grep lines that contain only decimal values

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file that contains lines of the type:

```
DRAM  ACCESSES  PER WALK          60.727888
L2 CACHE HITS   PER WALK          2083.990077
L2 CACHE HITS   PER tLB           0.846624
MMU    ACCESSES PER WALK          617298
MMU L4 MATCHES                  869
MMU NO MATCH                   1013
MMU TOTAL ACCESSES          625953
MMU L2 HIT   RATE             0.319430
MMU L3 HIT   RATE             0.012439
```

I wish to keep only lines that contain the decimal values. I tried

```
cat originalfile | grep *.[0-9] , grep [0-9].[0-9] , grep [0-9]\.[0-9]
```

but nothing seems to work. Please help me out.

Comment: @bartonchittenden : What woud be regexp to grep 4.4.1 from "  Version: 4.4.1"

Comment: I just found, grep -ri '^version\s*:\s*[0-9\.]\w*'

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the issue that you're having is that in regex '.' matches any character, not just the decimal point. Try

```
grep '[0-9]\.[0-9]' originalfile
```